# Is it possible to integrate Microsoft whiteboard in Angular web Application?

Tags: angular, web-applications, sdk, microsoft-teams, whiteboard

Is it possible to integrate Microsoft whiteboard in Angular web Application?

I am trying to integrate Microsoft whiteboard concept in angular web application.
During the meeting, we need to share whiteboard feature in the application.
while meeting users can share a whiteboard to make it available to all participants in a Teams meeting.

Kindly help me with proper solution and Reference link!!

Comment: Please refer this meeting stage view link:https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/meetings-stage-view/csharp which is in similar line of Whiteboard

Answer (score 1):

i am unaware of integrating ms whiteboard in angular, but you can try
https://github.com/webfactorymk/ng2-canvas-whiteboard
which is similar